# Relationshp between radius and height of cylinder with fixed volume.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Suppose there is a cylindrical container with a **fixed volume**. If the radius (*r*) increases by a **fraction** of *x* (meaning *x* is expressed as a percentage or fraction) what is the corresponding **fractional** change in the height (*h*) so that **the volume remains the same?**

Answer (score 1):

Another similar way.

Suppose two cylinders $(r_1,h_1)$, $(r_2,h_2)$. So , $$V_1=\pi\times h_1\times r_1^2$$ $$V_2=\pi\times h_2\times r_2^2$$ Now, say that the volumes are the same $V_1=V_2$; this gives $$h_1\times r_1^2=h_2\times r_2^2$$ Let us now change the radius such that $r_2=(1+x)r_1$ ($x$ being a fraction); then $$h_1\times r_1^2=h_2\times \Big((1+x)r_1\Big)^2=h_2(1+x)^2 r_1^2$$ So $$h_1=(1+x)^2h_2$$ or $$h_2=\frac{h_1}{(1+x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$V=\pi\times h\times r^2$

Lets say you doubled r to 2r.

Now $V=\pi\times h\times 4r^2$

Edited to add:  So, if you multiply the radius by $x$, you will have to divide the height by $x^2$

Comment: The answer you gave has two different volumes. I'm looking for how *h* changes to accommodate a change in *r* so that *V* **stays the same.**

Comment: Right.  What would you have to do to $h$ to make the 2nd volume equal the first one? I didn't want to flat out give the answer :)

Comment: is it *V* = (*π* X *h* X 4*r*^2)/4?

Comment: yes.  so if we increase r by 2, we have to decrease h by $2^2$ or 4.  Similarly, if you increase r by x, you would have to decrease, or divide, height by $x^2$

Comment: If you would post that final conclusion in the form of an answer, I would gladly accept it as correct.

Comment: If the increase to the radius was 25%, then would the decrease to the height have to be 25%^2 or 6.25%?

Comment: Not quite.  If the radius was increased by 25%, it is as if you multiplied the radius by 1.25.  so the height would have to be divided by ${1.25}^2$

Comment: does this take into account the constant product principle? A(1+r) X B(1-s) = AB when r is the fractional increase and s is the fractional decrease?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19133/discussion-between-turkeyhundt-and-user3308082).